# Handling UTF-8 input on stdin

Tags: rust

In [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html), rustaceans-to-be get to build a guessing game. In this guessing game, there's the following snippet:

```
let mut guess = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

Um... why would `read_line()` fail, I thought. And then found out the hard way: Instead of `50` I entered `5ß` (German keyboards...) and... read line failed.

So I thought I'd fix it quickly.

```
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess) {
    Ok(str) => str,
    Err(_) => println!("Please only enter ASCII characters.");
}
```

That returned a type mismatch: Expected `()`, found `usize`
Ah, right! `read_line()` returns the number of entered bytes in the `Ok` result. But I don't want to do anything with that information so I replaced the Ok statement from above:

```
Ok(_) => {},
```

That works. But is this the right way to do it? I'm basically telling the program to run an empty code block on `Ok`, which I'd consider bad style in languages like Java, PHP, JavaScript etc.

Comment: Rust is not ASCII-only, an input of `5ß` should be accepted by `read_line` just fine! The failure of `read_line` is reserved for IO errors when the standard input is redirected to e.g. a file on a network filesystem and that fails, or something like that. In other words, you shouldn't need to do anything special to "handle" UTF-8 input, it should just work. As a test, I tried entering `čć` to `read_line` in the guessing-game code, and it correctly responded with "You guessed: čć". What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10, albeit from the Eclipse-integrated console.

Comment: If it works correctly outside Eclipse, it sounds like an issue that should be reported to Eclipse or its Rust plugin.

Comment: High five! We just discovered something for Bugzilla :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're only interested in one of the match arms, you can use an [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html) binding:

```
if let Err (_) = io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess) {
    println!("Please only enter ASCII characters.");
}
```